# Calling variables in an alertbox

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anyway to run a script in an alert box?
My current code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello document.write(c1) users.");
</script>
```

I've tried :

```
<script>
alert("Hello <script>document.write(c1)</script> users.");
</script>
```

And my current code's alert box shows up as Hello document.write(c1) users.

Any help on this? c1 is supposed to call out their country taken from a script at my  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">var c1 = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)c1\=([^&]*)/)[2]);</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. `document.write()` modifies the web page, why would you want to do that while you're displaying an alert?

Comment: document.write(c1) would call out the variable c1 from the program i am using. It would display Hello USA users

Comment: It doesn't just call it out, it overwrites the document in the browser window with it.

Comment: What should i use instead of document.write()?

Comment: I already posted an answer!

Comment: woops didnt see that haha. let me try it

Comment: You should almost NEVER use `document.write()`. When you want to update the web page, you shoud use DOM modification functions.

Comment: ok gotcha. Thanks it worked. Will accept the answer once 7 minutes has passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string concatenation:

```
alert('Hello ' + c1 + ' users.');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Hello " + c1 + " users.");
</script>
```

You have to concatenate the variable into the alert outside of the string quotes. Document.write() only affects the document window, not the alert box.